# And operator to check equality between strings

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I'm trying to check if an element of a string has a blank space on the left and on the right. I'm trying to use an and operator in Python, but this error occurs:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

This is my code:

```
for i in range(0,len(s_sentence)-1):
    if (s_sentence[i-1]==' ' & s_sentence[i+1]==' '):
        [...]
```

How can I fix this? thank you!

Comment: Replace your `&` with an `and`

Comment: Use the `and` keyword.

Comment: As side note: you do not have to specify starting point for `range` if it is equal to 0, as it is default starting point. As you might check `print(range(0,12))` will give exactly same result as `print(range(12))`

Comment: note that that the `"a "` string could not give the result you expect. start your range from 1, not 0

Answer (score 3):

```
if (s_sentence[i-1]==' ' and s_sentence[i+1]==' '):
```

`&` is not the operator you're looking for, `and` is.

Sidenote: `&` does bitwise AND in Python